# Proof of the union of a collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A_i = (-i,i) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -i < x < i \}$. Find $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ and prove your answer.

I know that the answer is $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \mathbb{R}$, and I have started the proof in the following way:

First, we must show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. So, let $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i $. Then, there must exist some $i$ such that $x \in (-i,i)$, i.e. $-i<x<i$.

I am a little unsure where to go from this point. What I had thought about doing is letting $n$ be the smallest positive integer greater than $x$ so that $-n<x<n$ and $x \in A_n$, but then I am unsure where to proceed from there. Is this the correct way to go? If not, what should I do next?

I also need to prove that the intersection of the family of sets is $(-1,1)$, but I presume that this will be much easier.

Comment: That is the trivial part... By def $A_i$ is a set of *reals*: $A_i = \{ x \in \mathbb R \ldots \}$. and thus every $A_i$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA didn't even notice that. Thank you for pointing it out! Unfortunately that won't cut it for the reverse direction.

Comment: For the reverse direction, you have to prove that for every $x \in \mathbb R$ we can find $i$ such that $x \in A_i$. Consider [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) if $x > 0$ and floor if $x < 0$ and you have the needed interval.